Why are so many people telling me not to drop my PhD despite my lack of achievement, moving goalposts, and running out of funding? I don't understand
I'm a 5th year PhD in Experimental Psychology with an accepted MA from a different program. After I've consulted a ton of others recently on my decision to drop, many folks (including here) are telling me not to drop at all. I should note that I have a May 2025 graduation date on paper. However, given my advisor gave me answer that said the process isn't straightforward when it came to editing the Results section (we haven't touched the Discussion section yet), I doubt that May 2025 is viable. My advisor also said he doesn't mind the May 2025 date, albeit his only concern was that folks who extend that far out wait until the last second and he doesn't want that to happen. I also underachieved quite a bit throughout my PhD, which can be seen on the question related to not feeling like I learned enough skills. The jobs I want also don't require a PhD either.
It's worth noting that my university plans on cutting all four of its Psychology PhD programs in the future and the 5 year clock for current students to finish their programs has started for all but one program. This all came to a head when my stipend was cut in half my 3rd year and I ran out of funding my 4th year, which forced me to take a visiting position at a nearby college (which I bombed with many students telling me I was the worst instructor/professor at the college level they ever had).
So, why are many folks insisting that I finish despite my advisor moving the goalpost constantly, underachievement, and that I ran out of funding (I got a fellowship my 4th year too)? I've got more than enough reasons to quit yet many don't think I should've at all and that doesn't make sense to me. I know folks here can't read others minds or intentions, but I can't read others at all (even online) so I'd like to learn.

The answers you received to previous questions did state their reasons. You may think those reasons aren't very good, but that is something else than stating that they did not give reasons. Are you sure that you really don't understand their reasons, or that you just disagree with them?

Your relationship with online forums is unhealthy. You should be seeking advice on this exclusively from your family, advisor, and/or therapist. You must spend tens of hours per week writing these questions, arguing with the commenters, and ruminating. If you just spent this time working on your dissertation instead, you would probably be finished! For what it's worth, the 5-6 months between now and May 2025 seems sufficient to turn a fifth year ABD to a PhD holder.
